# Template variable injection in JS script

Tags: javascript, python, flask, chart.js

I have encountered a quite peculiar issue in my flask app trying to inject a template variable withing a Js script , I don't really understand what the problem is so here it goes.

I am specifically trying to inject two variables: a list of numbers and a list of strings (same length), so that I can plot the data on a `chart.js` plot.

The problem is that when injecting a single variable (the list of numbers) the page renders the pie chart with no errors, but then when i add the second variable (list of strings) the page goes blank.

Here is the JS snippet:

```
 <div class='chart'>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {{values}};
    var labels = {{labels}};
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                labels: '# of Votes',
                data: data,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255,1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
```

And flask:

```
@app.route('/test')

def test():
    screener = Signals()
    major_news = screener.major_news()
    distribution = screener.industry_distribution(major_news)
    
    return render_template('test.html', labels=[str(key) for key in distribution], values=[distribution[key] for key in distribution])
```

Keep in mind that the variables have both been checked and they both contain what they should.

In the JS script the `labels` variable is doing nothing but still throws an error as soon as declared.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of  [How can I pass data from Flask to JavaScript in a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178426/how-can-i-pass-data-from-flask-to-javascript-in-a-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refering to this SO Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48237270/17798307

> Flask provides a Jinja filter for this: tojson dumps the structure to a JSON string and marks it safe so that Jinja does not autoescape it.

Please try to declare your variables like this:

```
var labels = {{labels | tojson}};
```

Comment: Yes i thought about doing that but my object is not serializable as it is a list

Comment: OK. Maybe dump to json in python.`labels=json.dumps([str(key) for key in distribution])`

Comment: I made a python dict with the two lists and now it works. Thanks a lot for your help